# Error 415 Unsupported Media Type: POST not reaching REST if JSON, but it does if XML

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, post

I am actually new to REST WS but really I don't get this `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

I am testing my REST with Poster on Firefox and the `GET` works fine for me, also the `POST` (when it's a `application/xml`) but when I try `application/json` it doesn't not reach the WS at all, the server rejects it.

This is my URL: http:// localhost:8081/RestDemo/services/customers/add

This is `JSON` I'm sending: `{"name": "test1", "address" :"test2"}`

This is `XML` I'm sending:

```
<customer>
    <name>test1</name>
    <address>test2</address>
</customer>
```

and this is my Resource class:

```
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("customers")
@Singleton
@XmlRootElement(name = "customers")
public class CustomerResource {

    private TreeMap<Integer, Customer> customerMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Customer>();

    public  CustomerResource() {
        // hardcode a single customer into the database for demonstration
        // purposes
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Harold Abernathy");
        customer.setAddress("Sheffield, UK");
        addCustomer(customer);
    }

    @GET
    @XmlElement(name = "customer")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        customers.addAll(customerMap.values());
        return customers;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int cId) {
        Customer customer = customerMap.get(cId); 
        return  "{\"name\": \" " + customer.getName() + " \", \"address\": \"" + customer.getAddress() + "\"}";

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String addCustomer(Customer customer) {
         //insert 
         int id = customerMap.size();
         customer.setId(id);
         customerMap.put(id, customer);
         //get inserted
         Customer result = customerMap.get(id);

         return  "{\"id\": \" " + result.getId() + " \", \"name\": \" " + result.getName() + " \", \"address\": \"" + result.getAddress() + "\"}";
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is my Customer class:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: How does your `Customer` class look like? What JAXB annotations do you use on it?

Comment: Thanks, I updated to the code with my Customer class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is in the deserialization of the bean Customer. Your programs knows how to do it in XML, with JAXB as Daniel is writing, but most likely doesn't know how to do it in JSON.

Here you have an example with Resteasy/Jackson
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/

The same with Jersey:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: In these examples the input is exactly the same as mine, the return is different (like Daniel said) but my problem is ahead and I am not hitting the class at all.

Comment: @Maged do you use resteasy or jersey?

Comment: @Maged Did you update your web.xml like explained in the article?

Comment: Yeap I did add the mapping bit <init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>

Comment: @Maged can you try to remove the default constructor on your customer bean?

Comment: unfortunately it gives back same error and doesn't access the service...this is really weird because I found a lot of posts and everything seem to be fine and similar to what I have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14790/discussion-between-unludo-and-maged)

Comment: problem was that library jersey-jason was missing! Thank you.

Comment: where is the pom.xml file is located, i have found around 8 when i search in the folder please help

Comment: @Naveen did you download the project example?

Comment: No. i have downloaded http://www.mulesoft.com/ty/dl/studio-linux and i have tried one example http://blog.raml.org/mocking-service-walkthrough/. but it is have the same error message.  message = "Unsupported media type"; when i acces from ios device it is getting when browser it is working fine.

Comment: @Naveen pom.xml is specific to java code. iOs does not use java. This question is about java.

Comment: Solved the issue from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396696/415-unsupported-media-type-post-json-to-odata-service-in-lightswitch-2012 from the ios part we have to mention Make the Content-Type "application/json;odata=verbose" in your POST request

Comment: @Magini Have you solved this problem? I came across the same one.

Comment: very helpful description of the problem is available at http://ev9d9.blogspot.de/2013/05/doing-json-on-cxf.html

Answer (score 147):

Add `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json`
in REST Client header section

Comment: Where is the REST Client header section?

Comment: if you are using curl call from command line then you can add the header as follows:

[$> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"my_name","password":"123456"}' http://localhost:8080/url]

Comment: Need your help, i am new in this rest api creation, where is the EST Client header section is located?

Comment: For anyone who reached here from another language and that language was Ruby and you're using rest-client, this answer helped me a ton. Example usage `response = RestClient.post "https://pod12.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/sobjects/Contact/", {Email: user.email, LastName: user.last_name, FirstName: user.first_name, Phone: user.phone}.to_json, {Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}", :"Content-Type" => "application/json", :"Accept" => "application/json"}`

Comment: Helped me on Python as well. Remember to pass the payload as JSON: `requests.post("/login", data = json.dumps(loginCredentials), headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"})`

Comment: precise answer. It saved my time.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post a code example of how this is done within the context of the question.

Comment: If "Content-Type":"application/json" doesn't help, try "Content-Type":"text/xml"

Comment: My problem had nothing to do with JAXRS - I was trying to hand-make a request and the client header was not there.  This answered it for me.

Comment: @BadhonJain you will probably get a 406 response

Answer (score 19):

Just in case this is helpful to others, here's my anecdote:

I found this thread as a result of a problem I encountered while I was using Postman to send test data to my RESTEasy server, where- after a significant code change- I was getting nothing but 415 Unsupported Media Type errors.

Long story short, I tore everything out, eventually I tried to run the trivial file upload example I knew worked; it didn't.  That's when I realized that the problem was with my Postman request.  I normally don't send any special headers, but in a previous test I had added a "Content-Type": "application/json" header.  OF COURSE, I was trying to upload "multipart/form-data." Removing it solved my issue.

Moral: Check your headers before you blow up your world. ;)

Comment: +1 for the advice of "make sure the toaster is plugged in". Just had this same issue and it is easy to overlook when you are convinced the problem is in the code.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the following dependency was missing:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and found that the problem was that I had not registered the JacksonFeature class:

```
// Create JAX-RS application.
final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
    ...
    .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

Without doing this your application does not know how to convert the JSON to a java object.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson

Comment: can you explain a little more? I almost tried everything and I think I'm missing this point. where should I do this registration? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, I encountered this while starting a grizzly server. When started by IDE or mvn:exec everything properly, but not when using a jar with dependencies. You made my day sir !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

> curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d            '{"name":"json","surname":"gson","married":true,"age":32,"salary":123,"hasCar":true,"childs":["serkan","volkan","aybars"]}' XXXXXX/ponyo/UserModel/json

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8081 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
> PUT /ponyo/UserModel/json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 121
> 
* upload completely sent off: 121 out of 121 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Date: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 13:55:43 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

I resolved it by adding the dependency to pom.xml as follows. Please try it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>0.98</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue.
In fact, the request didn't reach the jersey annoted method.
I solved the problem with add the annotation: @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
The annotation @Consumes("*/*") don't work!

```
    @Path("/"+PropertiesHabilitation.KEY_EstNouvelleGH)
    @POST
    //@Consumes("*/*")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void  get__EstNouvelleGH( @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't return Strings in your methods but Customer objects it self and let JAXB take care of the de/serialization.

Comment: Could be but I think here the problem is ahead, I am not hitting the service at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, as it was giving **error-415-unsupported-media-type** while hitting post call using json while i already had the

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

and request headers as in my **restful web service using Jersey 2.0+**

```
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

I resolved this issue by adding following dependencies to my project

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
<version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

this will add following jars to your library :

1. jersey-media-json-jackson-2.25.jar
2. jersey-entity-filtering-2.25.jar
3. jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.4.jar
4. jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.4.jar
5. jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.4.jar

I hope it will works for others too as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

just change the content-type to application/json when you use JSON with POST/PUT, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to use ARC app from google and post a `XML` and you are getting this error, then try changing the body content type to `application/xml`. [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69eRt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in postman, i was selecting Accept in header section and providing the value as "application/json". So i unchecked and selected Content-Type and provided the value as "application/json". That worked!

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solution worked and you are working with JAXB, then you need to annotate your class with `@XmlRootElement`  to avoid `415 unsupported media type`

Answer (score 0):

you need to be consistent with choosing reactive or normal one that was my issue but after i changed it to reactive
it works fine.

```
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson")
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive")
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem while using in postman.
for POST request under header section add these as

key:valuepair

Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json

i hope it will work.