# RxJS - Angular2 - A watch to fetch Media types

Tags: angular, rxjs, media-type

I didn't find this in the documentation of Angular and RxJS. Is there any way to fetch a MediaType (img, video ..) data from an HTTP response an process/download it ?

The problem is that whether with the `get` or `head` HTTP method with an image (png) or an XML media type from the backend, I keep having the following HTTP error :

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

Here is the code, Version 1:

```
 return this.http.head(this.localBackURL + ressourcesPath.exportStatistiques, {search: params});
```

Version 2 :

```
 return this.http.head(this.localBackURL + ressourcesPath.exportStatistiques, {search: params});
```

Thanks

Comment: You can probably head and parse the headers from response.

Comment: Can you give information about the MediaType? Also, maybe some code would help to solve the problem

Comment: Can you please provide some code? The method to download the file, in which the error probably occurs, would be nice.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your time. I added the return method. There is nothing special other. the parameters can be deleted with the same result

Comment: It looks like both code lines are the same. Do you have any settings on the request? Like where you set Headers or something? Please take a look at the updated answer and the link provided there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understood the problem correctly.

But to get metadata from something, instead of using the 
`get` request method, you can use the `head` request method.

You can probably use this to get the information needed to decide if you want to proceed with the `get` method afterwards.

If you just want to download the file and then check for the MediaType you can read the headers after `get`ting the file.

**Update**
A quick google to the Error and I found the following. As there is currently no code for me to look at, I assume you'll probably have similar issues as I found.

[415 Unsupported Media Type - POST json to OData service in lightswitch 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396696/415-unsupported-media-type-post-json-to-odata-service-in-lightswitch-2012)

It looks like this Error happens if you have wrong `Content-Type` and/or wrong `Accept` Header settings.