# Jersey restful webservices in java application tested with Postman plugin sending complex Objects

Tags: java, json, eclipse, web-services, jersey

I have created one java restful ws with jersey 1.8 library, it is one post operation of a Pojo called Loc and consumes JSON format.

Here is the webservice:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import persistence.HibernateUtil;
import entities.Loc;

@Path("EnvironmentService")
public class Environment {


    @POST
    @Path("/post/location")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createLocation(Loc location) {

        System.out.println("ENTROU NO LOCATION");

        Session session = HibernateUtil.openNewSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(location);

        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        String result = "Location saved";
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }
```

I want to send the webservice a Loc object:

```
/**
 * Loc is a hibernate enitity class which represents a raw data table for location entries.*/

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Loc implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1184003645439013748L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private long time;
    private double accuracy;
    private String provider;
    @Column(name = "yProcessed", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default '0'")
    private int yProcessed = 0;
    @Column(name = "zClass", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "double default 0.0")
    private double zClass = 0d;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "latitude: " + latitude + " longitude: " + longitude + "time: "
                + time;
    }

    public double getAccuracy() {
        return accuracy;
    }

    public void setAccuracy(double accuracy) {
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
    }

    public int getyProcessed() {
        return yProcessed;
    }

    public void setyProcessed(int yProcessed) {
        this.yProcessed = yProcessed;
    }

    public double getzClass() {
        return zClass;
    }

    public void setzClass(double zClass) {
        this.zClass = zClass;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }
    public void setProvider(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml file for jersey configuration the jar i am using is 1.8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>RememberMeServer</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>webservices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And i am testing this webservice with the postman plugin in chrome.

I give him the following url `http://localhost:8080/RememberMeServer/rest/EnvironmentService/post/location`

which is correct.

I pass him the following header:

```
Content-Type application/json
```

and select `raw` and `JSON` type format and send the following JSON code **which was gathered using GSON from a Loc object**:

```
{"provider":"network","latitude":39.1237894,"longitude":-9.2501239,"accuracy":34.5,"time":1400957412206}
```

In the Postman plugin i get that `415: UnsupportedMediaType` and in eclipse i get this jersey error:

```
Mai 25, 2014 12:49:42 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class entities.Loc, and Java type class entities.Loc, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

Which is weird from what i understand the entities.Loc should be in here somewhere, but it is not.

Some anotations in class Loc are for Hibernate Framework and dont concern the webservice. i think they dont interfere.

i can't figure out how to pass this problem i want to test this webservice first and just after that i go to the client. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

here is the request preview in postman:

```
POST /RememberMeServer/rest/EnvironmentService/post/location HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"provider":"network","latitude":"39.1237894","longitude":"-9.2501239","accuracy":"34.5","time":"1400957412206"}
```

**EDIT2**

When i changed the type to text/plain and the parameter to a string it worked i think the problem is the mapping of the json string to Loc object any help?

**EDIT3:**

Now i changed the type to string in the post webservice and he receives the json pretty good  but how can i do it with a Loc object instead of a string?

**EDIT4**

By adding Genson has a user sugestion actually changed the error to internal server error here is the stacktrace:

```
Mai 28, 2014 2:12:26 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type class java.lang.String
    at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:127)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type class java.lang.String
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:442)
    at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:125)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonStreamException: Readen value can not be converted to String
    at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.valueAsString(JsonReader.java:193)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$StringConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:282)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$StringConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:269)
    at com.owlike.genson.convert.NullConverter$NullConverterWrapper.deserialize(NullConverter.java:57)
    at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:440)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the problem is that Jersey does not know how to map the json to your object.

You can use [Genson](http://genson.io/), when it is in your classpath JSON serialization/deserialization will automatically be enabled with Jersey.

Comment: i can put the .jar in my libraries in the project, but what do i have to do next? nothing?

Comment: indeed nothing - you can also remvoe all the json configuration stuff your web.xml

Comment: downlaod the latest here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.owlike/genson/0.99 - you directly get the jar from there even if you don't use maven

Comment: Ok, and you are refering to the        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param> in the web.xml right?

Comment: eugen please check my edit4. i did deleted the pojomappingfeature. i got that error now.

Comment: hum...check the json you are sending, you get this error if it reads a json object or array and tries to bind to a litteral like a string. You can also replace Lot by a Map<String, Object> and see what happens and what is in there. Also your setyProcessed wont match, the convention is setYProcessed (first char in upper case)

Comment: maybe i have to create the json using Genson as well and not Gson

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54635/discussion-between-eugen-and-joaofilipeclementemartins).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding no-argument constructor to your Loc class. As far as I am concerned, they are required - [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/).

Comment: Hum didnt worked. but i dont have that pom.xml file. how can i add it? this is a dynamic web project inside eclipse. I dont use maven.

Comment: pom.xml is for Maven-based project, used to manage dependencies. It very helpful, but not necessary for projects to work. Read this - http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: Yeah i get it. but why for example isnt entities.Loc in the MIME media types registered in jersey?

Comment: seems like some dependencies should be added - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if

Comment: those are for maven type project which i dont have