# Apache Jersey POST not working when posting JSON

Tags: json, jersey, java-7, pom.xml, tomcat8

I am using Apache Jersey and trying to POST valid JSON data to the service and it was giving me HTTP 415 error. So with the help of following links I was able to fix this error.

[Stack Overflow issue for the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if)

Basically I added some dependencies in pom.xml and some init-params in web.xml explained here

[This is in answer for above question](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

My method signature

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response postXXXX(final SomeObj obj) {
```

Now I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.xxx.ee.loggingapi.filter.HttpLoggingFilter.doFilter(HttpLoggingFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I searched the web for this error and found out some Stack Overflow threads but they are not helping me.

Below is my POM.XML related to jersey

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jersey -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I know the fact that I have 2 jars jsr311-api:1.1.1 and javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 which has a conflict for this issue but I am not sure how to resolve this.

**Update:**

So I removed below dependency from my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Also added below into my pom.xml for jackson json support

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I am getting below error.

```
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:274)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:368)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:738)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:491)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:395)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:738)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:491)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Mar 13, 2015 12:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:274)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:368)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:738)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:491)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:395)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:738)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:491)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 13, 2015 12:32:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/pmtplatform] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1107)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:274)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:368)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getAllRankedProviders(Providers.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.processResourceModel(ApplicationHandler.java:738)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:491)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:327)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Obliterate the first two dependencies. Anything you have that's `com.sun.jersey`, throw it out

Comment: For JSON support, use [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) (I prefer the first one - and match your Jersey version)

Comment: @peeskillet Removed those dependecy                                                                    Its throwing MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WADL
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.WadlModelProcessor.<init>(WadlModelProcessor.java:96)

Comment: I don't know. Can't reproduce the problem with what you've provided. But whatever you do, **do not** put those dependencies back. That was the cause of the main exception in your post.

Comment: I've never used 2.17, and don't have my IDE open to test, but try and set the Jackson provider version to the same version of the jersey-contianer-servlet. Not sure if it will make a difference or not

Comment: If that fails, start a new app from this Maven archetype `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes : jersey-quickstart-webapp : 2.15`. You should have no problems using this. Build on top of it. Might be something you're not showing us.

Comment: I was referring to wrong version i.e. 2.17 I changed that to 2.15 and it worked for me.