# How to Pass the DTO to the Restful web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0

This might be simple question. I tried googling but no luck.
I have one DTO which is pass from client and consumed by the restful webservices. But getting this exception

```
 Mapping exception to XML
avax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

and this is my restful method.

```
    @PUT
    @Path("microservice/persist")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public long update(AsyncJobDTO asyncJobDTO){
      //calling EJB and returing the value
      }
```

this is my restful call

```
http://localhost:9090/nexterp-war/rest/api/Jobupdate/microservice/persist?format=format.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because there was no accept header sent with the request. You need to send a `Accepts` and `Content-Type` headers with the client code.

Since your application accepted json, It should be

```
<code>'Accept': 'application/json'</code>
<code>'Content-Type': 'application/json'</code>
```

Similar posting in SO 
[Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json), 
[Error 415 Unsupported Media Type: POST not reaching REST if JSON, but it does if XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773846/error-415-unsupported-media-type-post-not-reaching-rest-if-json-but-it-does-if)

Comment: getting the same exception even after adding the Accept header( i m using postman)

Comment: Edited my post with additional header info.