# Creating an Uber Jar from a Jersey project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, jersey

I'm trying to create a uber jar from my jersey project in eclipse using maven. When running the project in eclipse it works well, but when I try to export the project to a jar file using maven the server seems to miss the JSON Provider.

The server starts without warnings, but every request to the server is answered with a HTTP error 415 (which is why I assume that the JSON Provider is missing like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826771/jersey-deserializing-json-when-using-local-jersey-httpserver))

I'v already tried many dependencies, build options, ... but non of them is working. I also tried the the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687312/jersey-fails-when-creating-uber-jar-with-maven-assembly-plugin), which seemed to be related, but it didn't work either.

This is the pom.xml I'm using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.picavi.json_rpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>PicaviJsonRpc_server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Unit test framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache logging framework API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache logging framework Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAX-RS for REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m07</version><!-- <version>2.0</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version><!-- <version>2.10.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version><!-- <version>2.10.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version><!-- <version>2.10.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler plugin that tells the compiler to use java-1.8 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Compile with tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.0-M1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Javadoc plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportOutputDirectory>docs</reportOutputDirectory>
                    <destDir>.</destDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>Picavi_JsonRPC_server</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.picavi.json_rpc_server.server.JsonRpcServer</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The project can be found [on github](https://github.com/tfassbender/picavi_json_rpc_server)

**Edit:**

After adding the `ServicesResourceTransformer` like mentioned in the comments the maven build looks like this (only the changed maven shade part):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>Picavi_JsonRPC_server</finalName>

                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.picavi.json_rpc_server.server.JsonRpcServer</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Adding this the build succeeds (like it did before), but starting the server I get the following errors:

```
    WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.JaxbStringReaderProvider$RootElementProvider] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 4
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllMethods(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:108)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerMethods(Utilities.java:1424)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:107)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:242)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitMethods(Utilities.java:220)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:145)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:158)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:337)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamExtractorConfigurator.lambda$init$0(ParamExtractorConfigurator.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.get(MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueParamProvider.get(AbstractValueParamProvider.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.PathParamValueParamProvider.createValueProvider(PathParamValueParamProvider.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueParamProvider.getValueProvider(AbstractValueParamProvider.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParamValueProvider(ParameterValueHelper.java:172)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:178)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:899)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.access$000(ComponentModelValidator.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator$1.run(ComponentModelValidator.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:147)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:257)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpHandlerContainer.<init>(JdkHttpHandlerContainer.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:90)
        at com.picavi.json_rpc_server.server.JsonRpcServer.startServer(JsonRpcServer.java:44)
        at com.picavi.json_rpc_server.server.JsonRpcServer.main(JsonRpcServer.java:23)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.get(LRUHybridCache.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:303)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.secureGetDeclaredMethods(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getDeclaredMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:192)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:193)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:84)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 77 more
MultiException stack 2 of 4
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllMethods(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getPostConstructMethod(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:184)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.access$200(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$1.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:64)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$1.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:60)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.findPostConstruct(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:119)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findPostConstruct(Utilities.java:1460)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getPostConstructMethod(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getPostConstructMethod(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:252)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getPostConstruct(Utilities.java:281)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:464)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2310)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:128)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1395)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1390)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:128)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1452)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1377)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:158)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:54)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:337)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamExtractorConfigurator.lambda$init$0(ParamExtractorConfigurator.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.get(MultivaluedParameterExtractorFactory.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueParamProvider.get(AbstractValueParamProvider.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.PathParamValueParamProvider.createValueProvider(PathParamValueParamProvider.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractValueParamProvider.getValueProvider(AbstractValueParamProvider.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParamValueProvider(ParameterValueHelper.java:172)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.createValueProviders(ParameterValueHelper.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkValueProviders(ResourceMethodValidator.java:178)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.checkMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitJaxrsResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodValidator.visitResourceMethod(ResourceMethodValidator.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethod.accept(ResourceMethod.java:899)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:162)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validateWithErrors(ComponentModelValidator.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.access$000(ComponentModelValidator.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator$1.run(ComponentModelValidator.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:147)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:257)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpHandlerContainer.<init>(JdkHttpHandlerContainer.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:90)
        at com.picavi.json_rpc_server.server.JsonRpcServer.startServer(JsonRpcServer.java:44)
        at com.picavi.json_rpc_server.server.JsonRpcServer.main(JsonRpcServer.java:23)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.get(LRUHybridCache.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:303)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities$3.run(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.secureGetDeclaredMethods(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getDeclaredMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:192)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.getAllMethodWrappers(ClassReflectionHelperUtilities.java:193)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:84)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl$3.compute(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 87 more
```

(this is repeated serval times; full stacktrace was too long to be added here)

The server seems to start anyway. When I try to connect to this server the HTTP error changes to error 500 (internal server error).

Comment: Are you also getting the same 415 error when running from the IDE?

Comment: @Daniele No when starting it from the IDE everything works just fine (server and client)

Comment: [And another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735728/2587435)

Comment: Add the `ServicesResourceTransformer` in your Maven shade plugin configuration.

Comment: Like I said in the question description, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735728/messagebodyprovidernotfoundexception-while-running-jar-from-command-line) doesn't seem to work for me. When I add the ServiceResourceTransformer to the shade plugin configuration, the server won't start but throws these exceptions: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext` or `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(...` The client then shows HTTP error 500.

Comment: I reopened the question. You should update the question adding the ``ServicesResourceTransformer` to your code (because you _do_ need this) and then post the full stack traces you are getting.